# Low microphone volume on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, microphone, headphones

I bought an external USB microphone (Klim Lingo) but the recording volume is too low. I tried to set 150% in pavucontrol but I can hardly hear my voice when recording it.

I tried with headphones and a usb-c => usb adaptater and I have the same problem. If I use another headphones on the jack plug, the microphone is well working.

My laptop is a Dell Latitude E5570 with Ubuntu 18.04 and I used several USB ports.

I also tried the microphone on another laptop with Windows 10 and it worked well without any configuration.

So what can I do to get this microphone well working?

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: Check this post, it's related to mic output volume: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1443659/why-does-my-microphone-max-out-at-50-volume/1451181#1451181

Answer (score 3):

Check the levels with `alsamixer` as they may be low there despite being higher in pulse audio. It is a terminal application.

Comment: Could you please give more details on how to "check the levels"? The alsamixer interface is very confusing... Thanks!

Comment: Those vertical bars are virtual faders. They have numbers below them, which should all be at 100.  If they're not, navigate to them (I think using the left and right arrows), and use the up arrow to raise the level.