# Why does my microphone max out at 50% volume?

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, 22.04, alsa, microphone

EDIT: I believe the problem is that my mic is a mono input and it is being treated as stereo, so it is only 50% volume because of this.

I am running Ubuntu 22.04.

I have a Blue enCORE 100i plugged into a Presonus AudioBox USB.

My Microphone volume never exceeds 50% at the OS. In the following screenshot you can see this is the maximum that the volume of the mic will go. The screenshot was taken while sound input was maximum at the mic (shouting "Why won't this work!!" lol).

[image]

On the AudioBox USB device, there is a clipping indicator light that indicates when the mic input exceeds max level. My clipping indicator light is going off, indicating that at the Audio interface, the microphone volume is max. But at the OS level it is only at 50%.

If I increase the gain in pavucontrol over 100% (as depicted) the max volume still stays at 50%. If I reduce the gain back down to 100%, the max volume is still 50%.

The output of `pactl info` is...

```
Server String: /run/user/1000/pulse/native 
Library Protocol Version: 35 
Server Protocol Version: 35
Is Local: yes
Client Index: 30 
Tile Size: 65472
User Name: scott
Host Name: main-desktop
Server Name: pulseaudio Server
Version: 15.99.1
Default Sample Specification: s16le 2ch 48000Hz
Default Channel Map: front-left,front-right
Default Sink: alsa_output.usb-PreSonus_Audio_AudioBox_USB-01.iec958-stereo
Default Source: alsa_input.usb-PreSonus_Audio_AudioBox_USB-01.analog-stereo
Cookie: 8641:298c
```

Comment: in a terminal write alsamixer check the settings for volume

Comment: It says "This device does not have any controls".

Comment: 22.04 does not use Pipewire. Pipewire was introduced in 22.10.

Comment: It could be because I personalised my installation that it uses pipewire on my system. 
I ran in a very simillar issue ones. Could it be his case ? @scorb

Comment: I use Ubuntu 22.04 LTS server with Cinnamon desktop 5.2.7 and kernel 6.1.6-060106-generic. But when I ps -e | grep pipewire I get results. referring to https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=273630

Comment: What's the output of `pactl info` ? @ Scorb

Comment: @Wingarmac I have updated the question.

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://superuser.com/questions/160425/ubuntu-best-way-to-set-microphone-volume-by-command-line @Scorb

Comment: In your case, it’s because it doesn’t show the right output level. Am I right ? It should show 100%, the indicator peaks at 50% instead, is it so?

Comment: @Wingarmac It is also quiet. For example in meetings and while gaming, everyone complains my mic is low.

Comment: Then I continue concentrate on my answer search to enforce the mic volume specifically. @Scorb

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142241/discussion-between-wingarmac-and-scorb).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My audio interface has two mono inputs. Pulse Audio was treating this as a single stereo input. So my mono mic was treated as the left channel of a stereo input. Because of this, it reserved the other 50% of volume overhead for the other channel.

My rather rudimentary solution was to buy a XLR splitter cable, so my mic now plugs into both the left and right channel. I now have a full volume stereo mic!

Answer (score 1):

### Help on troubleshooting/diagnose of the problem

I'm on Ubuntu 22.04 Jammy Jellyfish (x86-64) with Cinnamon 5.2.7

When I do:

- `ps -e | grep pipewire`

  ```
  2640 ?        00:00:00 pipewire
  2641 ?        00:00:00 pipewire-media-
  ```
- `ps -e | grep audio`

  ```
  2642 ?        00:17:13 pulseaudio
  ```
- `ps -e | grep alsa`

  ```
  nothing
  ```

Could you compare?

I presume sor far you use pulsaudio principaly, and think this might help:

If you experience low volume on your microphone try setting: `nano /etc/pulse/default.pa`

with:
`set-source-volume 1 300000`

Reference: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/PulseAudio/Troubleshooting

---

You could also check the setting in:

`/usr/share/pulseaudio/alsa-mixer/paths/analog-output.conf.common`

Look for `volume =` `merge` or `ignore` on your system ?

After changing it you should `killall pulseaudio`

Pulsaudio will restart on its own and you'll be able to try.

Normally it's advised to set `ignore` because the volume output of the microsophone is too high.

([*Reference in french*](https://doc.ubuntu-fr.org/pulseaudio))

---

If you try to make the input stereo instead of mono, I've found [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/1668184/how-to-change-all-mic-output-to-mono-from-stereo-in-linux) about adding a channel to an audio input.

*Microphones convert sound waves to audio signals via mic capsules. Most mics have one capsule that outputs one signal, making them mono devices. Some mics have multiple capsules and output multiple mono signals (which could be mixed in stereo). However, “stereo mics” are truly multiple-mono devices.* [Source](https://mynewmicrophone.com/do-microphones-output-mono-or-stereo-signals/)

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking me to edit /usr/share/pulseaudio/alsa-mixer/paths/analog-output.conf.common. What specific variable am I setting to what value?

Comment: What's the current output in the file on your system ?
Just do the oposite to try out the results and turn it back if it doesn't change anything.
Send back the results in your question edit. @Scorb

Comment: Just a heads-up to try to avoid downvotes or deletion -- When making a post like this, where you are trying to help *diagnose* the issue, but you still aren't confident that you have an answer, I usually find it best to state that up front.  Something along the lines of *"This is not a full answer, but some troubleshooting steps to try to hopefully help reach the answer ..."*.